# Period of trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, periodic-functions

How to prove the periodicity and then find the primitive period of summation, products and compositions of trig functions?
Is it possible to prove that the primitive period of sine function is $2\pi$ using its series definition? How to prove that the primitive period of tangent function is $\pi$ knowing that $\tan x =\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and that the primitive period of sine and cosine is $2\pi$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to specify what tools are allowed to answer your question. You can explain why the period is 2pi from basic definitions of sine and cosine with respect to unit circle. You can show the period is 2pi from the complex definitions of sine and cosine. Or is using $sin(x+2\pi)=sinxcos(2\pi)+cosxsin(2\pi)$ acceptable?

Comment: Your first question's answer will depend on the arguments of the trig functions involved.

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652080/concluding-that-sine-and-cosine-are-2-pi-periodic-from-definitions)

Comment: It is intuitive and easy to find the period of trig functions from their unit circle definitions as well as their graphs. But I really like to see a derivation that uses something other than intuition. Trig identities are useful but they can't give us the primitive period; they only give some period (e.g. 2π, 4π, ... and actually the derivation of these identities themselves rely on knowing the period). Since any number smaller than the periods we know, can be the primitive period, we can't test all of them. Can we use the series definitions of trig functions to derive their primitive period?

Comment: It is also possible to define trig functions using the complex exponential function and Euler's formula and then, use the properties of the complex exponential function (e.g. period) for the proof. But that requires knowing the period of complex exponential function over the real line (2π), which itself requires a derivation (probably using the intuition of the complex plane's unit circle or the periods of trig functions). So I guess the only way left, is to use series?